# How to read and write files into azure data lake

Tags: azure-functions, azure-data-lake

I need a bit of help with my azure function to be able to read and write files into data lake using C# (visual code). I do have visual studio 2019 available if needed.

**Update since I created the question**

> Is it possible to connect to data lake using a connection string?

**Code snippet**

```
  [FunctionName("MyExampleFunction")]
        public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("mytopic", "mysubscription", Connection = "myservicebus")]string mySbMsg, ILogger log)
        {
            // Save file into azure data lake
        }
```

First time writing azure functions, I'm using Visual Code and C# and I'm aware of the following library but not sure how to use it.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-datalake-extension/blob/master/samples/DataLakeExtensionSamples/OutputFromBlob.cs

I've come across this code whilst searching online but I'm not sure how to add the necessary extension within visual code, all my years of experience is within visual studo with nuget package manager.  I've looked at the visual code extensions panel but typing in 'service model' the extension doesn't come up..?

**Update**

```
private static void SaveToDataLake(string objectToSave)
        {
            var applicationId = "";
            var clientSecret = "";
            var tenantId = "";
            var adlsAccountFQDN = "";

            var creds = new ClientCredential(applicationId, clientSecret);
             var clientCreds = ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(tenantId, creds).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

             AdlsClient client = AdlsClient.CreateClient(adlsAccountFQDN, clientCreds);

             using (var stream = client.CreateFile(fileName, IfExists.Overwrite))
             {
                 stream.Write(objectToSave, 0, objectToSave.Length);
             }
        }
```

**Error message in portal**

[screen shot of error message received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGgwd.png)

Comment: take a look at the [sample repo](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/data-lake-store-adls-dot-net-get-started/tree/master/)?

Comment: I'm new to azure, to create the function I've created an azure free account and a data lake, I've now created a new role assignment to me.  Just trying to find out the application id, client secret, tenantid fqdn

Comment: It looks like you need an AAD setup to get those values for the code which to me, as a newbie to azure seems like a massive thing :-(

Comment: you can always consult the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal

Comment: thanks for that but when I load the app registrations within aad I get an error message at the top 'There was an error loading this content. Please refresh the page to try again.'  I've ignored that, created a registration and then clicked through to the subscriptions blade, if I click on 'add' at the top it redirects me to a new window for 'Add subscription' but after completing this and going back to the 'add' button it just relaunches the same 'Add subscription' screen?  It seems I can't add a subscription...?

Comment: you should probably create a support ticket for this. alternatively try another browser, incognito node

Comment: Have now tried incognito mode but still same issue.  Thanks